# Targeting combinations of letters with repetitions (IE: ? )

Tags: regex, rust

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match the following statements:

```
steal
stealer
photograph
photographer
```

But must not match:

```
steale
photographe
```

I tried the following RustExp, however the repetition only targets the R and not the E:

```
(steal|photograph)(er?)
```

*Note: This problem has been simplified from a much bigger regular expression and it's not feasible to use (steal|stealer|photograph|photographer) if it is at all possible to avoid it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `?` to the outside of the parens so that it applies to the whole group instead of just the `r` character:

```
(steal|photograph)(er)?
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=893f4f52df9f4cf5308d5e0c43760805))

Note that if you don't intend to capture the contents of either group, you can change them to non-capturing groups, which can increase performance as the group match doesn't need to be extracted:

```
(?:steal|photograph)(?:er)?
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but, on closer inspection, the tool I'm using has some quirks with validating that statement for some reason. Good to know it's the tool and not me.

(Context: I don't normally use Rust.)

Comment: I suggest you add word boundaries (`\b(?:steal|photograph)(?:er)?\b`) to avoid matching words like `'stealthy'` and `'radiophotograph'`.